# maven.elasticsearch.org returning a 404

Tags: maven, elasticsearch

We are running into an issue with our Maven dependency on the Elastic Search  Libraries that our code depends on in order to build / compile.

The build process fetched these libraries at build time, however the maven elastic search repository seems to be off line all together.

http://maven.elasticsearch.org/ currently returns a 404 resulting in everything below it being unavailable which results in the build process failing.

Even the maven central repo for elastic shield returns 404's https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/elasticsearch/plugin/shield/

I have sent an email to support@elastic.co asking them to turn the Elastic Repo back on, any other idea why this repo would just go offline and how would I go about rectifying it? A local onsite mirror of central, but it feels like overkill for what we need it for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official document [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/_using_elasticsearch_java_clients_with_shield.html)

The repository URL is : https://artifacts.elastic.co/maven/org/elasticsearch/plugin/shield/2.4.6/shield-2.4.6.jar

If you are using maven:

```
<project ...>

   <repositories>
      <!-- add the elasticsearch repo -->
      <repository>
         <id>elasticsearch-releases</id>
         <url>https://artifacts.elastic.co/maven</url>
         <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
         </releases>
         <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
         </snapshots>
      </repository>
      ...
   </repositories>
   ...

   <dependencies>
      <!-- add the shield jar as a dependency -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
         <artifactId>shield</artifactId>
         <version>2.4.6</version>
      </dependency>
      ...
   </dependencies>
   ...

 </project>
```

Comment: Unfortunately as of now (2021-12-15). This is also not working.